# Symfony 2 basic controller - return Response?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning Symfony 2 and I have problem:

My code is:

```
public function showListAction()
{
    $ar = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:ModGlobalAspectRatio')
               ->findAll();

    return $this->render('AcmeHelloBundle:Test:showList.html.php', array('recs' => $ar));
}

public function updateAction($id, $name)
{   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $ar = $em->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:ModGlobalAspectRatio')->find($id);

    $ar->setName($name);
    $em->flush();

    $content = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:showList');

    return new Response($content);
}
```

I run in "update" my first action "showList".

Without `return new Response()`  I have error:

```
The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?
```

I don't understand this why.. its litttle stupid..

My main question is:

Why after use `return new Response` I have text on top of page:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Fri, 28 Feb 2014 19:42:48 GMT X-Debug-Token: f0ada0 X-Debug-Token-Link: /symfony2/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f0ada0
```

I dont need this strange strings .. how Can I remove it ?

Thanks !! :)

Comment: Why not using `return $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:showList');` instead of using completely useless `$content` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return `$content`

```
public function updateAction($id, $name)
{   
    //...

    $content = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:showList');

    return $content;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your controller action is supposed to return a `Response` object. When you call `$this->forward();` in basic controller, it returns the required `Response`, which, in turn, must be returned by your controller action.